# Dto/TransactionScripts and Odata Services

Tags: odata, dto

With an odata service, we can query from the clientside without using dto. Do i really need dto layer if i use odata svc? What are the cons and pros if i don't use dto. In our old system for querying mechanism there are many query service-methods that returns dto collection. But odata services confuses my mind... It seems like; the responsibility of server moves to the client. The same confusion goes on, for transaction scripts. I'm curios about your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

When you are on the server side - the only thing that matters for oData is either a EDM model or POCO models. So when you genrate a EDMX file you can always considered those to be your business object or model layer and pump then in to those namespaces. So in a way there is no business logic that you are applying in there.

But on the client side you can always centralize the oData method invocation. Since they support callbacks you can always have a view model call up a repository and pass the call back. In this way you dont bloat your view model with extensive odata query invocation. Sort of repositroy pattern is what i am talking about.

Hope this gives you a direction.

regards :)

Comment: You say, the repository is in clientside and the models are in serverside. But isn't it weird? Thing we called "domain", is composed of repositories and models. But why do i need to seperate them to two diferent physical tiers?

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes - Repository is just a pattern. There is no labelling that this needs to be on the server side or client side. What i meant to say was - with WCF Data Service architecture - you just will have 2 files: 1 file which is the .EDMX and its corresponding .CS file where all the EF model reside, 2 file where the WCF Dara Service is defined. So this is all you need on the server side to have oData exposed. What i meant to say about client side was - a architecture to control the oData query invocation in one place. You can name it repository or even a plain class :)